Calculate the $PQ$ segment in the semicircle below

In the figure, if $MN = 40$ and $NQ = 9$,
Calculate $PQ$. $AB$ and $MB$ are diameters. (Answer: $21$)

Note: The question does not mention whether the diameters are equal. I don't know if it would be mandatory to get the result.

I try:
Let $AB = 2R$ and $MB=2r$
$\triangle MQB \sim \triangle MKN \implies \frac{BQ}{KN} = \frac{MQ}{KN} = \frac{2r}{MN}$
$\therefore \frac{BQ}{KN} = \frac{49}{KN} = \frac{2r}{40}=\frac{1}{20}$
$\triangle ABK\sim \triangle ABQ\implies \frac{2R}{2r} = \frac{KB}{KN} = \frac{AQ}{MQ}$
$\therefore \frac{R}{r} = \frac{KB}{KN} = \frac{AQ}{49}$
$\triangle OPQ: PQ^2 = R^2 - OQ^2 \implies PQ = \sqrt{R^2 - (R-BQ)^2} $

@JeanMarie  Thanks for the alert...I've already made the correction

FYI, since a circle can be drawn through any $3$ non-collinear points, and the only information about the circle with diameter $MB$ is that it goes through the $3$ vertices of a right-angled triangle, that information is superfluous. This includes whether or not its radius is the same as that of the other circle. It might have been stated just to throw people off from focusing on dealing with just the circle with center $O$, as I show in my answer where I solved the problem mainly using the power of a point in that circle.

Add the lower part of the circle with center $O$ and extend $MQ$ down until it meets this circle at the point $R$. Thus,
$$a = \lvert PQ\rvert = \lvert QR\rvert$$
Since $\lvert MQ\rvert = \lvert MN\rvert + \lvert NQ\rvert = 49$, we have
$$\lvert MP\rvert = 49 - a, \;\; \lvert MR\rvert = 49 + a$$
Since $\measuredangle MNK = \measuredangle MBQ$, we have that $\triangle MNK \sim \triangle MBQ$, so
$$\frac{\lvert MK\rvert}{\lvert MN\rvert} = \frac{\lvert MQ\rvert}{\lvert MB\rvert} \;\to\; \frac{\lvert MK\rvert}{40} = \frac{49}{\lvert MB\rvert} \;\to\; \lvert MK\rvert\cdot \lvert MB\rvert = 49(40) = 1960$$
By the Power of a point, and using the above $2$ equations, we get
$$\lvert MP\rvert\cdot \lvert MR\rvert = \lvert MK\rvert\cdot \lvert MB\rvert \;\to\; (49 - a)(49 + a) = 1960 \;\to\; a = 21$$

By the similitude of triangles $ANQ$ and $MBQ$ we get:
$$
9:AQ=QB:49.
$$
Hence:
$$
PQ^2=AQ\cdot QB=9\cdot49.
$$
